# How to Center an Image in Carousel?

Tags: html, css, carousel

I am new Here, I am making a Carousel and I want the image to be center, but if i change the orientation the image will be cut in half. what to do?

```
.carousel .item {

  margin: 0;
    height: 300px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

}

.item img {
    background-size: cover;
    top:  0;
    left: 0;.
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;

}

.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 40rem;
  margin: 0 auto;

}

carousel {
  margin: 25px 1 50px;
    background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
   border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
   display: flex;
width: 800px;
height: 400px;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-shrink: 0;
 
}
```

I tried changing the orientation of the image but still wont work, i was expecting it to be ad the center of my carousel without distorting the iamge

Comment: CSS without HTML is like wheels without a car. We cannot fully understand the problem without seeing the related HTML which the CSS is applied to. Please provide a [mre] of the issue. In the case of visual issues, a screenshot is often really helpful too. See also [ask]